# What is the scope of Application object properties and methods in excel-vba

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please give me an quick idea of the reach of application methods in Excel-vba.

I am trying to switch off 'drag & drop'-operations in Excel-vba to avoid loss of data in cells either filtered out or collapsed in a group. Only way I know to achieve this is something like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() 
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub
```

My experience is, that application methods affect everything in Excel. So when my Worksheet_Activate-event fires, drag & drop will get deactivated not only in the entire active workbook but in every workbook that is run on my machine at that time.

Am I correct in assuming further, that turning off 'drag & drop' will persist even beyond shutting down an re-starting Excel on my machine? Where would that be stored?

Will it be save to use application-methods on a machine where I am only a client user in an office network? Or in other words, do I risk incurring the wrath of any administrators for having turned off 'drag & drop' in their whole network?

Comment: FWIW, using `Application.CellDragAndDrop = True` within the same worksheet codesheet's `Worksheet_Deactivate` will not reset this application environment property when closing the workbook. `Worksheet_Deactivate` is only triggered by changing the `ActiveSheet` property (i.e. selecting another worksheet) not by closing the workbook.

Comment: Not sure how difficult it would be, but you might want to try playing around with the [`RevokeDragDrop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692643(v=vs.85).aspx) API function.  That might be a bit of overkill though.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid there is no single clear answer to your question. Each application environment setting must be judged individually.

- Some application environment properties are read only and cannot be programatically changed. Examples of this type would be `Application.ActiveCell` or `Application.ActiveWindow`.
- Some application members are not properties at all but commands. `Application.Calculate` forces a calculation cycle; it does not accept a value.
- Some application environment settings only persist for the duration of the sub and revert once the sub has completed. An example of this type would be `Application.DisplayAlerts` which can temporarily turn off annoying confirmation message boxes but turns back on again once the sub routine it was called in exits; i.e. it does not have to be programatically reset.
- Some application environment settings only persist until another action cancels them or they are programatically reset. An example of this type would be `Application.CutCopyMode`.
- Some application environment settings persist for the duration of the application instance. Shutting down Excel destroys the application object and restarting Excel instantiates another. Similarly, creating a second application instance after changing a setting in one would not inherit the changed environment.  Examples of this would be `Application.EnableEvents` or `Application.ScreenUpdating`. This type is typically reset when no longer needed; often at the end of a sub.
- Finally, some application settings semi-permanently change the options found within File > Options. These changes are retained by any future instance; whether Excel is shut down and restarted or another application instance in a separate workspace is created. A second application instance that was created before the change to the application environment was made is not affected. For all intents and purposes, you are rewriting Excel's startup options retained within the registry. Examples would be  `Application.ReferenceStyle` or `Application.UseSystemSeparators`.

Your `Application.CellDragAndDrop` falls into the last category. It is an Excel, Option that is retained in the current and all future application instances until it is reset manually through the GUI File, Options or programatically. If the workbook is opened on another computer, it has the potential to affect the Excel environment on that computer as well.

There is no setting that can change the Excel environment on machines across a network unless they open (and run) a workbook with macros. You would require an active directory network group policy for that.

Lastly, I will add a warning. I do not often get caught by someone else's workbook changing my own environment but one setting that I have been caught with is `Application.Calculation`. After opening up someone else's workbook, I find my own Excel environment left in `xlCalculationManual` which must be changed to `xlCalculationAutoMatic` through the GUI or VBA's Immediate window. While there is potential for causing a lot of problems with the application environment settings, I mention this specifically because it is by far the most common one I've run into and generally an innocent error; not a 'black-hat' effort. If your own formulas are not recalculating after opening someone else's workbook, check here first.

Comment: Great answer, especially the warning at the end.  I generally consider it a bug to leave a user's environment altered after your code is done unless that is the express purpose of the code.

Comment: @Comintern - Agreed, but that does not necessarily mean that someone else's code works the way it is supposed to. As a matter of fact, sometimes my own doesn't. :)

Answer (score 3):

The setting is persistent. Also, if you add it in worksheet events then if someone else opens your book and the macros run, they will "catch" it too.

You can minimise the scope by setting it False in the workbook_open event and then setting it True again in workbook_beforeclose. Thus it will only affect those workbooks where you want it and is less likely to mess up anyone else's Excel application.

```
Private Sub workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
End Sub
```

Someone requested the _open event. Here you go.

```
Private Sub workbook_Open()
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you included a snippet of the Workbook_Open event setting the property to False.

Comment: Lol, my concern was limiting the scope, since OP already knows how to disable it, but ... done.

Comment: Sure, but when someone comes along in 6 months and reads your answer it will be better for them :)